# Surface across a cone without resorting to divergence theorem

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

This question has plagued me since the start of the semester more than 2 months ago. 
I find myself without any solution to this problem.

$$\mathbf{F}=(-x,-y,z)$$ across the surface S that is part of the cone $$z=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$ that lies between the planes $z=1$ and $z=2$ and has inward orientation.
Find the flux.

I've tried using spherical coordinates but found myself stuck. 
Cylindrical might work but suppose I'd like the see the solution developed as a consequence of solving the problem in Spherical coordinates, is that possibile?

Comment: @Chappers The tag name looks really awkward; since we can't have an apostrophe, I suggest (stokes-theorem), following the (frequently used) form "Stokes' theorem" [one can also think of it as derived from "the Stokes theorem"].

Answer (score 0):

In spherical coordinates, the vector field is
$$ F = (-r\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi},-r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi},r\cos{\theta}). $$
Simple enough. The cone is given by $r\cos{\theta}=\sqrt{r^2 \sin^2{\theta}(\cos^2{\phi}+\sin^2{\phi})} = r\sin{\theta},$
i.e. $\tan{\theta}=1$, or $\theta=\pi/4$. The surface we integrate over has $0<\phi<2\pi$, and $1<r\cos{\theta}= \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}<2$.

Now for the surface element. The normal to the surface is $-e_{\theta}$, by staring at it (it's a $\theta=$const surface, after all...), and the area element is $r \sin{\theta} dr d\phi$ (from the all-time classic Wikipedia article, [Del in cylindrical and spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)). So after all that, we can set up the integral, after remembering $e_{\theta} = (\cos{\theta}\cos{\phi},\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi},-\sin{\theta})$:

$$ -F \cdot e_{\theta} = r(\cos^2{\phi}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}+\sin^2{\phi}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}+\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} ) = 2r\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta} = r\sin{2\theta} = -r. $$
Therefore the $\phi$ integral is trivial and gives the usual $2\pi$. The rest of the integral is
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{r=\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}} r \, dr = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(8-2), $$
I think, so I get $ \frac{6\pi}{\sqrt{2}},  $ if I haven't forgotten anything.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinate is probably the only way. Spherical coordinate seems like the best solution but it's way too messy.

Comment: Fundamentally you have the choice of having a messy vector field, a messy surface, or messy boundary conditions, and almost never can you have none of these (law of conservation of mess in vector calculus).